# Simple open-source-CMS working with hiphop php?

Tags: php, content-management-system, hiphop

Hiphop from Facebook don't like eval() or create_function().

Are there good open source php-CMS which work with hiphop almost out of the box?
Drupal is not compatible as far as I know.

If possible, are those cms multi-site-enabled (one code base hosts several sites with different db-connection-strings).

I think that hiphop php could be a good choice for Amazon EC2 it could save a lot of money.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: Hiphop is rubbish, don't use it, problem solved.

Comment: hiphop won't speed up the page by a relevant factor

Answer (score 1):

Back in 2009, PHP creator Rasmus Lerdorf [made a presentation for the Digg folks](http://talks.php.net/show/digg), in which he demonstrated numerous performance profiling techniques.  It takes 20 slides to get there, but he demonstrated that **conventional performance profiling techniques can be just as effective at increasing performance as HipHop**.

Forget HipHop.  Profile your code to identify bottlenecks, then remove them.

Comment: I want to use the cms as a framework where i can integrate modules into it which depends heavily on the user account logged in. A little bit like facebook - i know that the database is the weak point. But given the db is no problem are there any php-cms out there? Even if there are only 10-20% per cent improvement with hiphop it is a good starting point.

Comment: No, it's actually an *awful* starting point.  It's a wrecking ball when you need a scalpel.  It's a *last resort*.  Please review the presentation.  You can get an entirely equivalent bang for your development buck by actually understanding the code's performance characteristics.